# ifstream from next/new line in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, ifstream

I am having set of data stored in a file which are basically names. My task is to get all the first letters from each name. Here is the file:

```
Jack fisher
goldi jones
Kane Williamson
Steaven Smith
```

I want to take out just first word from each line(ex. jack, goldi, kane, Steaven)
I wrote following code for it, just to take take out 2 names. Here it is:

```
    string first,last;
    ifstream Name_file("names.txt");
    Name_file>>first;
    Name_file>>endl;
    Name_file>>last;
    cout<<first<<" "<<last;
```

it is giving error. If I remove endl, it takes the first full name(Jack, fisher) whereas I want it should take (jack ,goldi). How to do it ? Any idea? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: `Name_file>>endl;` Remove this. It is unnecessary. The extraction operator skips whitespace before the words. Also, even if it was needed, it is in the wrong place. The newline is after `last`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Name_file>>endl;` is always wrong.

Even then, you can't use `>>` like that, it will stop on a space, which is why when you remove `endl` you see the problem that `first` and `last` contain only the first line.

Use `std::getline` to loop over your file instead and get the full names, then split the line on the first space to get the first name:

```
ifstream Name_file("names.txt");

std::string line;
while (std::getline(Name_file, line))
{
  std::string firstName = line.substr(0, line.find(' '));
  //do stuff with firstName..
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `std::istringstream` with `operator>>` to extract the first name from each `line` that is read: `while (std::getline(Name_file, line)) { std::istringstream iss(line); std::string firstName; iss >> firstName; ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Though I don't mind "Hatted Rooster"implementation I think it can be a little less efficient when the input suddenly contains a very long line.

I would use `ignore()` to remove the rest of the line:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream nameFile("names.txt");
    std::string firstName;

    while (nameFile >> firstName)
    {
        // You got a first name.
        // Now dump the remaing part of the line.
        nameFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your query.

```
ifstream Name_file;
string line;
Name_file.open("names.txt");
if(Name_file.fail()){ cerr<<"Error opening file names.txt !!"<<endl;return;}

vector<string> v; // array to store file names;

while(Name_file >> line){
    string word;
    getline(Name_file, word);
    v.push_back(line);
}

// printing the first names
for(int i = 0; i < v.size();i++){
    cout<<v[i]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons

Comment: @HattedRooster Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @MartinYork Is it better now or should I remove the answer as a whole. And thanks for pointing out such rookie mistakes :)

Comment: Inside the `while` loop, you can use `Name_file.ignore()` instead of `std::getline()` to skip the rest of the current line (see MartinYork's answer). There is no need to waste a `std::string` that is not going to be used for anything.